# Auth fail with Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp

Tags: c#, sftp

I´m try to connect with a SFTP and in the connection line throw the "Auth fail" error.
I´m using Tamir.SharpSsh dll.

My code:

```
Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp sftp = new Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp("Host", "Username", "Password");
sftp.Connect(22); //Port
```

StackTrace:

```
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect(Int32 connectTimeout)
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect()
at Tamir.SharpSsh.SshBase.ConnectSession(Int32 tcpPort)
at Tamir.SharpSsh.SshBase.Connect(Int32 tcpPort)
```

(The user and the password are correct)

Thanks, and sorry for my english.

Comment: The port is ok, and the error is displayed quickly.

Comment: Are you putting the host in a good format? I personally use it like this: `new Uri("sftp.domain.com", UriKind.AbsoluteOrRelative).ToString()`

Comment: @Justin Pihony I just tried, but the error was the same. Any other ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: No, this works for me as long as all the data is correct. You aren't putting the folder path in are you? It should be the base domain address.

Comment: The folder path is input in the "GetFileList" method, not in the conection, and this works only with some sftp

Comment: I not know the difference between these SFTP, but with some it works.